# Perl - Global symbol $DIR requires explicit package name (why can't I print the output?)

Tags: perl

```
#!/db/pub/infra/CPAN/perl/5.8.8/bin/perl

use lib '/db/pub/eq/arina/global/perl/lib';
use lib '/db/pub/infra/CPAN/perl/5.8.8/lib/site_perl/5.8.8';

use DBI;
use strict;

sub main {

    my $dir = "/data/dbxpc2_archive/BookingManager/2017-01-12/data/PC1/millennium.ignore.ftp.noencrypt.DB_USD";

    my @files = glob "${DIR}/*.csv";

    print @files;
}

main();
```

Comment: Because `$DIR` is a different variable than `$dir`.

Comment: `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: @stevieb: *"Global symbol $DIR requires explicit package name"* indicates that they have at least `use strict 'vars'` in place.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you are using a variable (`$DIR`) you never declared. You do have a declared a variable named `$dir` which appears to be the one you intended to use.

```
glob "${dir}/*.csv"
glob "$dir/*.csv"
glob $dir."/*.csv"
```

Your code mishandles paths with spaces, `*`, `?`, etc. Fix the injection bug using

```
glob "\Q${dir}\E/*.csv"
glob "\Q$dir\E/*.csv"
glob quotemeta($dir)."/*.csv"
```